# How is Cocoa : addObserver working under the hood?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications

how does `addObserver:` works under the hood ? Since Objective C can't overload operators...

Are class `@properties`, or object references stored implicitly in a `NSDictionary`, which can monitor value access ? Or how can cocoa observe values ?

And especially when we write the getter and setter of property by ourself,
how does the observer notification happen?

Comment: You should have a look at [this article](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html). It explains how the KVO mechanism creates subclasses at runtime and overrides the observed setter methods.

Comment: please post this as an answer, so i can mark it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The KVO mechanism creates subclasses at runtime and overrides the observed setter methods.
[This excellent article of Mike Ash](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-23.html) explains how it is implemented.